# R Metrics auc() error message

Tags: r, metrics, roc, glmnet, auc

I'm trying to calculate `auc` but have a weird problem.  When I run this script:

```
rm(list = ls(all = T))
gc()

library(Metrics)
library(glmnet)

nrows <- 92681
set.seed(456)
df1 <- data.frame(act1 = round(runif(nrows), 0), pred1 = runif(nrows))

Metrics::auc(df1$act1, df1$pred1)
glmnet::auc(df1$act1, df1$pred1)
```

I get:

```
> Metrics::auc(df1$act1, df1$pred1)
[1] 0.4930949
> glmnet::auc(df1$act1, df1$pred1)
[1] 0.4930949
```

When I add one more row and run this:

```
rm(list = ls(all = T))
gc()

library(Metrics)
library(glmnet)

nrows <- 92682
set.seed(456)
df1 <- data.frame(act1 = round(runif(nrows), 0), pred1 = runif(nrows))

Metrics::auc(df1$act1, df1$pred1)
glmnet::auc(df1$act1, df1$pred1)
```

I get :

```
> Metrics::auc(df1$act1, df1$pred1)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In n_pos * n_neg : NAs produced by integer overflow
> glmnet::auc(df1$act1, df1$pred1)
[1] 0.5011554
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Metrics::auc` uses a formula which includes the value `(n_pos * n_neg)` in the denominator, which in this case is 'sum(actual == 1) * sum(actual == 0)' which evaluate to **integers** `46308 * 46374 = 2147487192`, which exceeds the largest **integer** you machine can handle (i.e. `.Machine$integer.max`).

For example:

```
46308 * 46374
#> 2147487192

as.integer(46308) * as.integer(46374)
#> [1] NA
#> Warning message:
#> In as.integer(46308) * as.integer(46374) : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Comment: In short, this is a category of problem where the denominator is large if done the naive way, but there are lower memory ways of calculating it.  I don't have time to code up a solution, but all you need to know is that the AUC is the mean of (a > b) for all values `a` among the cases and values `b` among the controls.  You can partition the values among A and B and average the two.  For example, you could use binary splits on your cases and controls, use the AUC method within those splits and then average the results appropriately (according to the size of the split).

Answer (score 0):

Just modified the function:

```
AUC <- function(y_pred, y_true){
            rank <- rank(y_pred)
            n_pos <- as.numeric(sum(y_true == 1))
            n_neg <- as.numeric(sum(y_true == 0))
            auc <- (sum(rank[y_true == 1]) - n_pos * (n_pos + 1)/2)/(n_pos * n_neg)
            return(auc)
}
```